# how to convert a specific html section to powerpoint format, ie ppt?

Tags: html, reactjs, powerpoint

I have a requirement in my current React project, to convert the current page's specific div to .ppt (not pdf or image) from the client side.
Is there anyway to do this directly?

Comment: Client side or server side? If it is server side, it has nothing to with `reactjs`.

Answer (score 2):

finalOutputDoc.Save(@"C:\temp\temp.html", Aspose.Pdf.SaveFormat.Html);

```
        //Next convert to powerpoint
        //Create Empty presentation instance//Create Empty presentation instance
        //using (Aspose.Slides.Presentation pres = new Aspose.Slides.Presentation())
        //Create Empty presentation instance//Create Empty presentation instance
        //Create Empty presentation instance//Create Empty presentation instance
        using (Presentation pres = new Presentation())
        {
            //Acesss the default first slide of presentation

            ISlide slide = pres.Slides[0];

            //Adding the AutoShape to accomodate the HTML content
            IAutoShape ashape = slide.Shapes.AddAutoShape(ShapeType.Rectangle, 10, 10, pres.SlideSize.Size.Width - 20, pres.SlideSize.Size.Height - 10);

            ashape.FillFormat.FillType = FillType.NoFill;

            //Adding text frame to the shape
            ashape.AddTextFrame("");

            //Clearing all paragraphs in added text frame
            ashape.TextFrame.Paragraphs.Clear();

            //Loading the HTML file using stream reader
            TextReader tr = new StreamReader(@"C:\temp\temp.html");

            //Adding text from HTML stream reader in text frame
            ashape.TextFrame.Paragraphs.AddFromHtml(tr.ReadToEnd());

            //Saving Presentation
            pres.Save(@"C:\temp\output.pptx", Aspose.Slides.Export.SaveFormat.Pptx);

        }
```